# Taylor series and extrapolation 2

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, extrapolation

[image]

Hey guys, I've finished the first three parts, but I have no idea how to approach part d and part e. Any hints would help! Thanks!

Update: I've finished the first three parts. For part d, I found the taylor series for $sin(x)$. Since $p_k=ksin(\pi/k)$, I substitute x with $\pi/k$ and I get $p_k=\sum_{j=o}^\infty(-1)^jk(\pi/k)^{2j+1}/(2j+1)!$= $\sum_{j=o}^\infty(-1)^j(\pi)^{2j+1}k^{-2j}/(2j+1)!$. And I did the same with $P_k$. But still I don't know how to connect what I got with part d.

Comment: Relevant (for continuity of the question, not as a duplicate since you are now asking about parts (d) and (e)): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663672/use-two-formulas-to-approximate-pi

Comment: Now, for (d): when $k\to \infty$, we have $\frac{\pi}{k} \to 0$, and we have the taylor series for $\sin$ atound $0$ being $$\sin x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.$$ In particular, this gives $k\sin \frac{\pi}{k} = \dots$. (And similar for $P_k$ with $\tan$.)

Comment: Got it! In part e, how is h related to the process of approximating $\pi$?

Comment: The first term in the expansion of $k\sin(pi/k)$ will be $k \pi/k=pi$.

Comment: Then there would be no $k$ and no $h$

Comment: But k will still appear in the other terms.

Comment: So I need to solve e by computing $p_k$ and $P_k$ just like I did in part c and then substitute $h$ with $k$?

Comment: Looking at the question, that's what I'd gather, yes.

Comment: I know how to represent $ksin{\pi/k}$ using taylor series for sin around 0, but I don't know how to connect it with the question. I still can't see the connection between them..

Comment: Where did you get so far? For instance, did you obtain the expression $$p_k = \pi + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j\pi^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}k^{-2j}$$?

Comment: I got almost the same answer as yours except I don't have that $\pi$ in my answer. I just substitute $x$ with $\pi/k$ in the taylor series. Where did you get that $\pi$?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add what you did? I'll detail my comment once home.

Comment: Sure. Thank you so much!

Comment: See my answer. From what you did, the next step is to treat separately the term $j=0$ and the rest ($j\geq 1$), as the first term is actually equal to $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

For (d): we will use the Taylor series for $\sin$ and $\tan$, [namely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Series_definitions)
$$
\sin x = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!}x^{2j+1}, \quad
\tan x = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{U_{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}x^{2j+1}
$$
for some constants $(U_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$.

**Detailed derivation:**

We now have, for any $k\geq 4$,
$$
\begin{align}
p_k &= k \sin \frac{\pi}{k} = 
k \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!} \left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)^{2j+1} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!} \frac{k\pi^{2j+1}}{k^{2j+1}} 
= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!} \frac{\pi^{2j+1}}{k^{2j}} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^0}{(2\cdot 0+1)!} \frac{\pi^{2\cdot 0+1}}{k^{2\cdot 0}} + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!} \frac{\pi^{2j+1}}{k^{2j}} \\
&= \pi + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!} \frac{\pi^{2j+1}}{k^{2j}} \\
&= \pi + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{q_j}{k^{2j}} 
\end{align}
$$
for $q_j \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{(-1)^j\pi^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}$.

Similarly,
$$
\begin{align}
P_k &= k \tan \frac{\pi}{k} = 
k \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{U_{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!} \left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)^{2j+1} \\
&= \pi + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{U_{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!} \frac{\pi^{2j+1}}{k^{2j}} \\
&= \pi + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{Q_j}{k^{2j}} 
\end{align}
$$
for $Q_j \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{U_{2j+1}\pi^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}$.

Comment: According the question, I think we should be finding some like $p_k=\pi-\sum$ so that we'll get $\pi=p_k+\sum$? Your answer basically says that $\pi=p_k-\sum$? but I don't see any mistakes in your answer, which makes me confused..

Comment: @J.doe  **We** get to define the $q_j$... I should have defined them with a minus sign (the opposite of what they are right now) to match the problem statement.

Comment: Oops....you are absolutely right! Thank you!

Comment: And for part e, which is pretty similar to part c. For part c, I calculate the answers manually, which is a disaster. Is there any faster way to solve problems like part e?

Comment: Not quite sure -- to calculate $p_k$ and $P_k$, you mean?

Comment: I think so, because in part c, I approximate $\pi$ by computing $p_k$ and $P_k$.

Comment: And I did that manually, which takes me quite a long time. For part e, the required accuracy is $10^{-12}$, if I solve that by hand, I think that would be way more time consuming than solving for $10^{-4}$. I am wondering if there is any shortcut to solve the problem.

Comment: The long part is "only" to figure out which $k$ you should get to (i.e., the minimum $k$ giving you that accuracy). For that, you can use theorems on the remainder of a Taylor series, e.g. [Taylor-Lagrange.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)

Comment: I'll take a look at that. Thank you so much!